# Issue with register device in MFP8.0

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We are developing **ionic app with mfp8.0**. We have tried to register our device for push notification by using the following code,

```
 function isPushSupported() {
    MFPPush.isPushSupported(
        function(successResponse) {
            alert("Push Supported: " + successResponse);
            registerDevice();
        }, function(failureResponse) {
            alert("Failed to get push support status");
        }
    );
  }

 function registerDevice() {
      WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
          MFPPush.registerDevice(
              null,
              function(successResponse) {
                  alert("Successfully registered");
              },
              function(failureResponse) {
                  alert("Failed to register device:" + JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
              }
          )
      );
   }
```

Not able to register the device now. **While getting inside the registerDevice() function  App is getting stopped.**

*Actually, We are getting this error recently. Before that the same code was working fine for us.*

I have referred the documentation. But, I am not getting the solution.Link which I have reffered is,

> https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsCordova/blob/release80/www/js/index.js
>
> https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/

Note:
  GCM recommeded to make use of FCM now, refer the following link,

> https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Actually, after register my device with **FCM credentails** only I am facing the issue.

**Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!**

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the FCM site or in the MFP site? You should follow ONLY the instructions in the **MFP** site. Additionally, which Android OS are you trying this on, Android 6 or Android 7?

Comment: From mfp server we have opened https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/      this given link. Its automatically going to FCM only. we are using android 6+

Comment: Can you please follow the instructions in the developer center instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are following the correct instructions. The instructions are layed out in the following page: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/

1. Visit the Firebase Console.
2. Create a new project and provide a project name.
3. Click on the Settings "cog wheel" icon and select Project settings.
4. Click the Cloud Messaging tab to generate a Server API Key and a Sender ID. and click Save.

Comment: I have followed your given steps. Still I am not able to register device. I am getting the following error,
"com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushException:Response:Status=500,Text:{\"errorCode\"\"UNEXPECTED_ERROR\",\"errorMsg\":\"Unexpected error encountered\"}

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting that error. Please feel free to open a PMR (support ticket).